# Private variables for Public Accessors in an entity class. c#

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to understand best practice compared to what I've seen and currently use. In the following code example, we have an entity class with NO in-class methods. The class is just a field list.

```
/// <summary>
/// AddUserID
/// </summary>
public string AddUserIDField = "Add_User_ID";
public string AddUserID
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Row != null)
            return (string)mmType.GetNonNullableDbValue(this.Row["Add_User_ID"], 
                "System.String");
        else
            return this._AddUserID;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.Row != null)
            this.Row["Add_User_ID"] = value;

        this._AddUserID = value;
    }
}

private string _AddUserID;
```

What use here is the private string? It isn't used or accessed within the class itself. Couldnt you just replace the _AddUserID references to AddUserId?

This is my companies framework, not EF.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `_AddUserID` is where you actually store the value that `AddUserID` refers to. If you do the replacement you ask about, the property will just keep calling itself in an infinite recursion.

Comment: c# isnt smart enough to create that variable for you?

Comment: Only if you use [auto-implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties).

Comment: Thanks bud. Gave me a good lead on research

Comment: Think about `AddUserId` as about a function.

Comment: Seems like you should replace the `Row["Add_User_ID"]` references with `Row[AddUserIDField]`, unless that field is for something else?

Comment: Short way: `_AddUserID` is a field, & `AddUserID` is a property (with getter & setter functions). A field is a variable declared as back-end to store property value like Java does, but in C# case there's auto-properties which declares getter & setter functions automatically.

Comment: Except you can't use auto-properties when you need custom `get` and `set` methods...

Answer (score 0):

In C#, when you write `public string MyVar { get; set; }` it is actually producing this code:

```
// The private variable holding the value of the property
private string _myVar;

// The getter and the setter of the property
public string MyVar {
    get
    {
        return _myVar;
    }
    set
    {
        _myVar = value;
    }
}
```

So a property always have a underlying private variable. The property is simply a syntax to hide a getter and a setter. It does not hold a value in itself. The fact that you can most of the time write a property without writing the associated private variable is just syntaxic-sugar offered by the C# compiler (see [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) for more information).

In the case of the code you presented us: since the code is using a specific getter and setter it has to explicitly write the private variable that is usually hidden behind a property.